# Don't show windows that aren't really in this workspace?

Tags: unity, workspaces

I use four workspaces in Ubuntu 15.04 and a window and I've noticed that sometimes a window will have a few mm poking down into the adjacent workspace, and as a result, <kbd>super</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> allows me to switch to the window. But since it is only visible as a tiny thread a the edge of the workspace, I can't even tell where it is.

Is there any way to ensure that if I switch to a window I'm switching to the workspace where the majority of the window is?  Or any creative ways to handle this that you've worked out?